# What are right parameter types of ODCIIndexInsert in case of creating indextype 'WITH ARRAY DML' option (documentation mismatch)

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

During developing Domain Index for Oracle 11.2.0.1.0 (problem also appears in 12с) i was faced with misunderstanding of parameter types of function
**ODCIIndexInsert** in case of creating indextype  **WITH ARRAY DML** option

According to Oracle documentation
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e10765/ext_idx_ref.htm#i76892

In case of WITH ARRAY DML option Oracle will invoke ODCIIndexInsert with following signature

```
FUNCTION ODCIIndexInsert(
  ia ODCIIndexInfo,
  ridlist ODCIRidList,
  newvallist varray_of_column_type,
  env ODCIEnv)
RETURN NUMBER
```

In my case indexed column has datatype NUMBER so i defined **varray_of_column_type** as **SYS.ODCINumberList**

```
STATIC FUNCTION ODCIIndexInsert(ia in sys.ODCIIndexInfo, ridlist in sys.ODCIRidList,  newvallist in sys.ODCINumberList, env in SYS.ODCIEnv) RETURN NUMBER
```

Indextype was created as

```
CREATE INDEXTYPE test_index_type
FOR
test_eq(number, number)
USING index_methods
WITH ARRAY DML(number, sys.ODCINumberList)
WITH LOCAL RANGE PARTITION
WITH SYSTEM MANAGED STORAGE TABLES;
```

or

```
CREATE INDEXTYPE test_index_type
FOR
test_eq(number, number)
USING index_methods
WITH ARRAY DML
WITH LOCAL RANGE PARTITION
WITH SYSTEM MANAGED STORAGE TABLES;
```

(problem occurs in all cases)

```
CREATE TABLE test_table (id NUMBER (19,0));
CREATE INDEX test_index ON test_table(id) INDEXTYPE IS test_index_type;
```

When attempting to insert data in the table

```
insert into test_table values (1);
```

oracle raise exception

```
Error starting at line 53 in command:
insert into test_table values (1)
Error at Command Line:53 Column:1
Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-29925: cannot execute SCOTT.INDEX_METHODS.ODCIINDEXINSERT
ORA-06553: PLS-306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'ODCIINDEXINSERT'
ORA-06553: PLS-306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'ODCIINDEXINSERT'
29925. 00000 -  "cannot execute %s"
*Cause:    The specified function does not exist or does not have an
           appropriate signature.
*Action:   Implement the function with the appropriate signature.
```

So my question is.
Is it normal behavior of oracle (according to documentation)?
What is **correct signature** of **ODCIIndexInsert function** in case of INDEXTYPE creation with **'WITH ARRAY DML'** option and fact that indexed column has **NUMBER** datatype?

By the way if i define indextype  **without** 'WITH ARRAY DML' option signature is clear, and working. But this approach doesn't satisfies our performance needs.

Also if i define index type with option 'WITH ARRAY DML WITHOUT COLUMN DATA' and use signature

```
static function ODCIIndexInsert(ia sys.odciindexinfo,   ridlist sys.odciridlist, env sys.ODCIEnv) return number
```

Everything works too. But this approach doesn't satisfies our business needs.

**Is it a way to define ODCIIndexInsert  parameter types (in case of indexing number column)  so that batch inserting works according to documentation?**

```
FUNCTION ODCIIndexInsert(
      ia ODCIIndexInfo,
      ridlist ODCIRidList,
      newvallist varray_of_column_type,
      env ODCIEnv)
```

I am attaching full sql script to recreate environment and reproduce the problem.

Type definition:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE index_methods AS OBJECT
(
  step number,
  STATIC FUNCTION ODCIGetInterfaces(ifclist OUT SYS.ODCIObjectList) RETURN NUMBER,
  STATIC FUNCTION ODCIIndexCreate (ia SYS.ODCIIndexInfo, parms VARCHAR2, env SYS.ODCIEnv) RETURN NUMBER,
  STATIC FUNCTION ODCIIndexAlter (ia sys.ODCIIndexInfo, parms IN OUT VARCHAR2, altopt number, env sys.ODCIEnv) RETURN NUMBER,
  STATIC FUNCTION ODCIIndexDrop(ia SYS.ODCIIndexInfo, env SYS.ODCIEnv) RETURN NUMBER,
  STATIC FUNCTION ODCIIndexExchangePartition(ia SYS.ODCIIndexInfo, ia1 SYS.ODCIIndexInfo, env SYS.ODCIEnv) RETURN NUMBER,
  STATIC FUNCTION ODCIIndexUpdPartMetadata(ia sys.ODCIIndexInfo, palist sys.ODCIPartInfoList, env sys.ODCIEnv) RETURN NUMBER,
  STATIC FUNCTION ODCIIndexInsert(ia in sys.ODCIIndexInfo, ridlist in sys.ODCIRidList,  newvallist in sys.ODCINumberList, env in SYS.ODCIEnv) RETURN NUMBER,
  STATIC FUNCTION ODCIIndexDelete(ia SYS.ODCIIndexInfo, rid VARCHAR2, oldval number, env SYS.ODCIEnv) RETURN NUMBER,
  STATIC FUNCTION ODCIIndexUpdate(ia SYS.ODCIIndexInfo, rid VARCHAR2, oldval number, newval number, env SYS.ODCIEnv) RETURN NUMBER,
  STATIC FUNCTION ODCIIndexStart(sctx IN OUT index_methods, ia SYS.ODCIIndexInfo,
    op SYS.ODCIPredInfo, qi sys.ODCIQueryInfo, strt number, stop number, cmpval number, env SYS.ODCIEnv) RETURN NUMBER,
  MEMBER FUNCTION ODCIIndexFetch(self IN OUT index_methods, nrows NUMBER, rids OUT SYS.ODCIridlist, env SYS.ODCIEnv) RETURN NUMBER,
  MEMBER FUNCTION ODCIIndexClose(self IN index_methods, env SYS.ODCIEnv) RETURN NUMBER
);

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE BODY index_methods IS

STATIC FUNCTION ODCIGetInterfaces(ifclist OUT sys.ODCIObjectList) RETURN NUMBER IS
BEGIN
  ifclist := sys.ODCIObjectList(sys.ODCIObject('SYS','ODCIINDEX2'));
  RETURN ODCIConst.Success;
END ODCIGetInterfaces;

STATIC FUNCTION ODCIIndexCreate (ia sys.ODCIIndexInfo, parms VARCHAR2,  env sys.ODCIEnv) RETURN NUMBER IS
BEGIN
  RETURN ODCIConst.Success;
END ODCIIndexCreate;

STATIC FUNCTION ODCIIndexDrop(ia sys.ODCIIndexInfo, env sys.ODCIEnv) RETURN NUMBER IS
BEGIN
  RETURN ODCIConst.Success;
END ODCIIndexDrop;

STATIC FUNCTION ODCIIndexAlter (
  ia sys.ODCIIndexInfo,
  parms IN OUT VARCHAR2,
  altopt NUMBER,
  env sys.ODCIEnv)
RETURN NUMBER IS
BEGIN
  RETURN ODCIConst.Success;
END ODCIIndexAlter;

STATIC FUNCTION ODCIIndexUpdPartMetadata(
  ia sys.ODCIIndexInfo,
  palist sys.ODCIPartInfoList,
  env sys.ODCIEnv)
RETURN NUMBER IS
BEGIN
  RETURN ODCIConst.Success;
END ODCIIndexUpdPartMetadata;


STATIC FUNCTION ODCIIndexExchangePartition(
  ia sys.ODCIIndexInfo,
  ia1 sys.ODCIIndexInfo,
  env sys.ODCIEnv)
RETURN NUMBER IS 
BEGIN
  RETURN ODCIConst.Success;
END ODCIIndexExchangePartition;



STATIC FUNCTION ODCIIndexInsert(
   ia sys.ODCIIndexInfo,
   ridlist sys.ODCIRidList,
   newvallist sys.ODCINumberList,
   env sys.ODCIEnv)
RETURN NUMBER IS
BEGIN 
  return ODCIConst.Success;
END;

STATIC FUNCTION ODCIIndexDelete(
   ia SYS.ODCIIndexInfo,
   rid VARCHAR2,
   oldval number,
   env SYS.ODCIEnv)
RETURN NUMBER IS
BEGIN
  return ODCIConst.Success;
END;


STATIC FUNCTION ODCIIndexUpdate(
   ia SYS.ODCIIndexInfo,
   rid VARCHAR2,
   oldval number,
   newval number,
   env SYS.ODCIEnv)
RETURN NUMBER AS
BEGIN
  return ODCIConst.Success;
END;


STATIC FUNCTION ODCIIndexStart(
  sctx IN OUT index_methods,
  ia SYS.ODCIIndexInfo,
  op SYS.ODCIPredInfo,
  qi sys.ODCIQueryInfo,
  strt number,
  stop number,
  cmpval  number,
  env SYS.ODCIEnv)
RETURN NUMBER AS 
BEGIN
  sctx := index_methods(1);
  return ODCIConst.Success;
END;


MEMBER FUNCTION ODCIIndexFetch(
  self IN OUT index_methods,
  nrows NUMBER,
  rids OUT SYS.ODCIridlist,
  env SYS.ODCIEnv)
RETURN NUMBER AS
BEGIN
  return ODCIConst.Success;
END;


MEMBER FUNCTION ODCIIndexClose(self IN index_methods, env SYS.ODCIEnv) RETURN NUMBER AS
BEGIN
  return ODCIConst.Success;
END;

end;
```

Problem workaround:

```
--drop function test_eq_fun;

CREATE FUNCTION test_eq_fun(a number, b number) RETURN NUMBER AS
BEGIN
  IF a = b then
    RETURN 1;
  ELSE
    RETURN 0;
  END IF;
END;

--drop operator test_eq;
CREATE OPERATOR test_eq
BINDING (number, number) RETURN NUMBER
USING test_eq_fun;


--drop indextype test_index_type;
CREATE INDEXTYPE test_index_type
FOR
test_eq(number, number)
USING index_methods
WITH ARRAY DML(number, sys.ODCINumberList)
WITH LOCAL RANGE PARTITION
WITH SYSTEM MANAGED STORAGE TABLES;

/*
CREATE INDEXTYPE test_index_type
FOR
test_eq(number, number)
USING index_methods
WITH ARRAY DML
WITH LOCAL RANGE PARTITION
WITH SYSTEM MANAGED STORAGE TABLES;
*/


--drop table test_table;
CREATE TABLE test_table (id NUMBER (19,0));

CREATE INDEX test_index ON test_table(id) INDEXTYPE IS test_index_type;


insert into test_table values (1);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was given correct answer at  https://forums.oracle.com/thread/2582903 so i cross post research hear to fill knowledge base.

If you want to use 'WITH ARRAY DML' option. You must implement BOTH single row version of insert method and multi row version of insert method.

When you insert single row, oracle always invokes single row version of method.

But when you insert multiple rows at ones oracle invokes combination on single and multi row methods.

If your table is not partitioned then oracle invokes multi row version is you are inserting two or more records.

If table is partitioned than ODCIIndexInsert will be invoked for each section in which data are inserting. So if you insert 5 rows in 5 partitions (1 row per 1 partition) Oracle will invoke single method 5 times.
But if you are inserting two or more rows in partition oracle will invoke multi row version of method for that partition.

Hope this will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Please also note that 
1) even the WITH ARRAY DML option does not guarantee Oracle to INSERT all rows in one single call to ODCIIndexInsert. I have seen examples where Oracle will call the ARRAY DML version of ODCIIndexInsert multiple times to insert all the rows. In my example Oracle was constantly changing nrows between 200 and 53 rows every time. I assume this depends on SGA memory size, buffer settings and the size of rows to insert.
If you know how to avoid this I'd like to know

2) ODCIIndexDelete does not have similar WITH ARRAY DML option. This is slowing down DELETE's significantly since it has to be done 1 row at a time. The funny thing is that Oracle Text cartridge object TextIndexMethods has ODCIIndexDelete defined with interface for array dml (ridlist ODCINUMBERLIST).

Comment: 1) This is expected behavior to divide batch into smaller chunks. I don't know way to avoid this and in general we should not (in case oracle choose effective batch size)

Comment: 2) Delete and Update doesn't have batch counterpart methods. For my OLTP system it is not an issue because we are not deleting records and updating indexed columns. But this might be an issue for other kind of applications. Oracle Text use undocumented indextype modifier 'without column data  with array dml'. You can define this modifier for your own indextype and be able to use array dml same as oracle text does. But this bulk methods doesn't receive modified data array (only row id array). You even can't query underlying table to retrieve this data via row id (forbidden during modification)

Comment: 'without column data with array dml' modifier is only suitable for building 'offline' kind of indexes. This indexes doesn't rebuild instantly when dml is performed on table. You must rebuild them manually from time to time to reflect changed data (as Oracle Text  
requires).